# Special filter pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe:

```
   BPR_free_speed  BPR_speed  Volume  time_normalised  free_capacity  
0           17.88  15.913662     580         1.593750          475.0  
1           17.88  15.865198     588         2.041667          475.0  
2           17.88  16.511613     475         0.666667          475.0  
3           17.88  16.882837     401         1.091458          467.0  
4           99999  16.703004     438         1.479167          467.0  
5           17.88  16.553928     467         0.960417          467.0
```

How can I get a Series on special conditions?
I want to find outliers and put them in the series `df["has_outliers"]`, like if a row has a value more than 550 in any column, then True, otherwise False.

The output for this dataframe should be

```
     has_outliers
0           True
1           True
2           False 
3           False 
4           True 
5           False
```

I think it can be done even using numpy, but how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one True per row:

```
df["has_outliers"] = df.gt(500).any(axis=1)
```

Or count `True`s and cast to integers:

```
df["has_outliers"] = df.gt(500).sum(axis=1).astype(bool)
```

Comment: Thank you for a such fast answer!
Is it possible to get the inverse labels? (False instead of True and vice versa)

Comment: @cicaduze - sure, use `df["has_outliers"] = ~df.gt(500).any(axis=1)` - add `~` for inverse condition

Comment: Sorry, I cant upvote for your comment, but thank you very much. You are the best time-saver ever!